# How to use gesture events through javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do mobile based gesture events, without the use of hammer.js ,can we achieve the functionality without including hammer.js?

Comment: Well, given that hammer.js is a javascript library, the yes, whatever that can do, you can do in vanilla js too.  Question being, why you'd want to rebuild something?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcouse you can, as James said it is afterall a JS library

you can get current mouse coordinates with

```
var x = event.clientX;     // Get the horizontal coordinate
var y = event.clientY;     // Get the vertical coordinate
```

and you can push these in some data structure or directly analyze the stream of inputs and recognize gestures